# Mutate a column based on a named vector, like a lookup table

Tags: r

```
blah <- data.frame(
  x = 1:3,
  y = rnorm(3)
)

named_vect <- 1:3
names(named_vect) <- c('blah', 'dog', 'cat')
```

I wouldlike to create a new column based on the values of variable x, where the number in x corresponds to the name of the corresponding number in named_vect.

```
blah <- blah %>% 
  mutate(text_name = ???)
```

Desired output:

```
  x          y text_name
1 1 -0.2390928      blah
2 2 -0.8818895       dog
3 3  0.1537032       cat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `recode` if we reverse the name, value of 'named_vect'

```
library(dplyr)
named_vect <- setNames(names(named_vect), named_vect)
blah %>% 
    mutate(text_name = recode(x, !!! named_vect))
```

-output

```
#  x          y text_name
#1 1 -2.0009292      blah
#2 2  0.3337772       dog
#3 3  1.1713251       cat
```

---

Or using `base R`, we match the 'x' by converting to `character` to match the names of the 'named_vect'

```
blah$text_name <- named_vect[as.character(blah$x)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `match()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
blah <- blah %>% 
  mutate(text_name = names(named_vect)[match(x,named_vect)])
```

Output:

```
  x         y text_name
1 1 2.4290706      blah
2 2 0.5817137       dog
3 3 0.7392442       cat
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `match`

```
transform(
  blah,
  text_name = names(named_vect)[match(x, named_vect)]
)
```

or `stack` + `merge`

```
merge(blah, setNames(stack(named_vect), c("x", "text_name")))
```

gives

```
  x          y text_name
1 1  0.6207273      blah
2 2 -0.2710539       dog
3 3  2.0738347       cat
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
data.table(blah)[data.table(stack(named_vect)), on = .(x = values)]
```

gives

```
   x          y  ind
1: 1 -1.2302276 blah
2: 2 -0.8073727  dog
3: 3 -0.2389972  cat
```